# how to sort by percent inside foreach

Tags: php, sorting, filter, foreach

please, how to sort by percent? Inside foreach ?

this is how I have built the code

```
foreach($rows as $data) {
 $percent = 80; //this is the result I will get
 echo "<div>Product has $percent %</div>";
}
```

I have a percentage calculation inside

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense as described: if the percentage is always 80, there isn't any sorting to do; and I don't know what "sorting inside foreach" would mean. However, this reference will hopefully help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Comment: the value is still not 80. In foreach I have a function to calculate the percentage of ratings.

Comment: I presumed that was the case, but the code you've given here is simplified so much that it's completely impossible to answer the question. See if the reference I linked helps you make a first attempt, and read the tips on creating a [mcve] if it doesn't work out

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about php but to keep it simple I would do the calculations, sort the data in the table and then display the table. However, if you want to do this on the fly you would need to have an array/list where the new elements are inserted in the correct order after each calculation. Perhaps php has such a collection available. I don’t know.